# stop sequenced animation in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a sequenced animation started by button A, how can I stop the animation by button B？thank you

Answer (score 1):

Store your animation in a state variable and call `start` or `stop` when you click a button:

```
constructor() {
    super(props);

    var my_animation = ... // define your animation here

    this.state = {
        my_animation: my_animation;
    }
}

startAnimation() {
    this.state.my_animation.start();
}

stopAnimation() {
    this.state.my_animation.stop();
}

render() {
    <Button onPress={() => this.startAnimation()} />
    <Button onPress={() => this.stopAnimation()} />
}
```

For more info on `start` and `stop` see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html

Comment: Sorry about not making the question clear, I actually want to start the animation by button A and stop it by button B

Comment: thx @FuzzyTree, put up a sample here, but not working as expected :( 
https://rnplay.org/apps/PozUMg

Comment: @GerardTaub I don't see a single call to `stop()` in your example ... you didn't follow the answer